# c++ - order of construction and destruction

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, destructor

I have the following C++ code (VS2013):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
    int i;
public:
    A(int i) : i(i) {
        cout << "DEFAULT CTOR " << i << endl;
    }
    A(const A &o) : i(o.i) {
        cout << "COPY CTOR " << i << endl;
    }
    ~A() {
        cout << "DTOR " << i << endl;
    }
    friend A f(const A &, A, A *);
};
A f(const A &a, A b, A *c) {
    return *c;
}
int main() {
    f(1, A(2), &A(3));
}
```

It produces the following output:

> DEFAULT CTOR 1
>
> DEFAULT CTOR 3
>
> DEFAULT CTOR 2
>
> COPY CTOR 3
>
> DTOR 2
>
> DTOR 3
>
> DTOR 3
>
> DTOR 1

The first 3 are parametric constructors (wrongfuly outputing "DEFAULT CTOR" but that doesn't matter), which are called prior to calling `f`.

Then, when the `return *c;` line is run, the copy constructor with value 3 is run, followed by the destruction of the object with value 2.

Finally, at the end of `main`'s scope, the remaining objects (3, 3, 1) are destructed.

I don't understand this behavior, and found no explanation to it.

Can anyone elaborate as to the order of things happening?

Specifically:

1. Why is the third object `&A(3)` constructed before the second object `A(2)`? Does this have anything to do with their creation (the third is by reference, the second is by value), or with the way `f` is defined (the second  is by value, the third is a pointer)?
2. When `return *c;` runs, a copy of the third object is created to be returned. 
   Then, the only object being destructed before returning is the second object. Again, does this have anything to do with their creation, or with the way `f` is defined?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you call "DEFAULT CTOR" is *not* the default constructor. A default constructor can be called with *no* arguments.

Comment: As for your first question, the [evaluation order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) of arguments is not specified. It can be anything the compiler wants.

Comment: Some programmer dude, yes, you are correct. I will edit my post now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is the third object &A(3) constructed before the second object A(2)? Does this have anything to do with their creation (the third is by reference, the second is by value), or with the way f is defined (the second is by value, the third is a pointer)?

It happens because the evaluation order of function arguments is left unspecified by the C++ standard. A compiler can evaluate them however it likes. This is the cause of many instances of undefined behavior, when programmers that are unaware of this rely on sequencing that isn't there.

> When return *c; runs, a copy of the third object is created to be returned. Then, the only object being destructed before returning is the second object. Again, does this have anything to do with their creation, or with the way f is defined?

Kind of, yes. The `A(2)` object is created by direct initialization of an argument to the function `f`. The scope of function parameters is the body of the function. So `A(2)` goes out of scope the moment the function exits. The other objects have a slightly longer lifetime, because they are created outside the function and are passed by reference/pointer. They exist until the end of the full expression `f(1, A(2), &A(3));`, so they are destructed later.